# Is the equation of motion for a spring-damper system the same whether oriented upward or downward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, spring, oscillators

So every spring-damper system I've found online has the equation of motion:

$$mx''+cx'+kx=0$$

I can understand how this is derived when downwards is positive, but what about when upwards is positive?  Wouldn't it be

$$mx''-cx'-kx=0$$

[image: How I derived the equations]

Comment: Where is the acceleration directed to ?

Comment: Well if the mass was pulled down and released:

mx'' directed upwards
k(s+x) directed upwards
cx' directed upwards
mg directed downwards

right?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\hat d$ and $\hat u$ be unit vectors in the down and up direction.

Looking at your right (correct) derivation you have made down $\hat d$ as positive and the displacement of the mass from the equilibrium position is $x \hat d$ leading to the velocity being $\dot x \hat d$ and the acceleration being $\ddot x \hat d$.

So your equation of motion is $mg \hat d - ks \hat d - kx \hat d - c \dot x \hat d = m \ddot x \hat d \Rightarrow  m\ddot x \hat d + c \dot x \hat d + k \hat d = 0$

To change from having down as positive to having up $\hat u$ as positive all you have to do is note that $\hat d = - \hat u$ and substitute for $\hat d$ into the equation which was derived was having down as positive.
You will find that you get the same equation of motion.

So what was wrong with your left hand derivation?

You made the displacement of the mass $-x \hat u$ and the velocity of the mass $- \dot x \hat u$ but what you failed to do was to make the acceleration $-\ddot x \hat u$

Comment: in problems where the force doesn't depend on the displacement, like the mass sliding down an inclined plane or free fall, if we change the positive direction, the right hand side of the equation $m\ddot{x}$ doesn't get a negative sign. For example, in free fall, if we take downward direction to be positive then $mg=m\ddot{x}$. This would give us $x=1/2 gt^2$. However, if we take the upward direction to be positive, we would have $m\ddot{x}=-mg$ and $x=-1/2 gt^2$ which essentially means the same thing, as the displacement in the upward direction is now negative.

Comment: In this problem where the force depends on the displacement, why is it important to change the sign of acceleration, once we switch the positive direction ? In the two problems I stated above, we didn't flip the signs, and our final answer just came out negative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

This is because your 2nd equation *should* read as

$$ -mx''-cx'-kx=0 $$

since the sense where positive $x$ is has switched. This means a sign change for $x$, $x'$ and $x''$.